# Why the dimension of output LSTM layer can be either 2 dimension or 3 dimension?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network

why the dimension of LSTM output is 2 or 3 but the dimension of LSTM input is always 3 dimension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dimension of LSTM input has to be described with (sample_number, unit_number, feature_number). The dimension of LSTM output has to be 3 when the task is many-to-many and you are using TimeDistributed layer, because `return_sequence` has to be `true` which means you are getting all hidden states values instead of only the last value as the default.